# Need for velocity as rate of change of displacement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, velocity, rotational-kinematics

Think of the following 2 cases:

1. An object is in rotation. Take a quarter arc of a circle. The initial and final points of that quarter arc are $A$ and $B$. if we have the arc length as $l$ and time taken to be $t$, then speed is $\frac{dl}{dt}.$ here $l$ is distance.
2. Draw the line segment $AB$. Here $AB=S$ is displacement. now velocity is $\frac{ds}{dt}.$

What is the need for drawing an extra straight line and consider $\frac{ds}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{dl}{dt}$? why define velocity to be the rate of change of displacement? Why not just stick with the rate of change of distance? Is there any example to show why this is helpful?

Comment: Given two points at different points in space I would love to take the one which is a straight path joining the two points and not any curved one . This is the use of displacement I guess.. at least it tells us about the shortest route

Answer (score 1):

I think what your $2^{nd}$ point is trying to say is that velocity is a vector quantity, and so it should be given by displacement per unit time.
Remember, distance is a vector quantity with a direction, that is along the line joining the two points. Distance is a scalar, in this case, the arc of the circle. THe line joining the two points would be the displacement.

However, with that said, the second point gives you the average velocity.

In the case of circular motion, the instantaneous velocity is given by $v=\omega r$, where $\omega$ is angular velocity. It is basically the time taken to complete one rotation(revolution).

From here, you get, $v=\frac{2\pi}{T} r$

If you know the time taken to traverse the distance $l$, you'd easily find the time taken to cover the full circle. This would be the time period $T$. Plug this back into your equation, along with the radius $r$, and you'll obtain your velocity vector, which would have a direction, that is tangential to that particular point.

Moreover, you do not need derivatives to define velocity here, as you have been provided with a distance. Your velocity would be just $\frac{l}{t}$.

$\frac{AB}{t}$ would have been the average velocity.

For example, suppose the particle does a full revolution. its average velocity would be $0$ as its displacement is 0. However, it would still have an instantaneous velocity, acting in a tangential direction to that point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to know how does displacement give a direction to velocity but distance doesn't?why not define velocity as distance by time also?

Comment: This is because distance does not have a direction, it is defined that way. It is a scalar. Displacement on the other hand is a vector.  Speed is a scalar, like distance. Velocity again is a vector.

Comment: Moreover, there is a difference between average velocity and instantaneous velocity. Remember, instantaneous velocity acts along the tangent to a point, and the magnitude of the instantaneous velocity is the same as the speed i.e. arc length/time. This is what you see in a speedometer. Average velocity is the displacement divided by time taken. This can also be $0$ when the particle returns to its original position.

Comment: How is displacement vector?

Answer (score 0):

One is the distance traveled and one is the change in location. Different things. You can wonder in a circle and end up back where you started, zero displacement, long distance traveled. Maybe someone interested in one but not the other, or in both.

---

Secondly, velocity is an *instantaneous* quantity. It is an infinitesimal change in location over an infinitesimal time. You wrote $\frac{d \vec{s}}{dt}$ when you meant $\frac{\Delta \vec{s}}{\Delta t}$, where $\frac{\Delta \vec{s}}{\Delta t}$ is “average velocity”.

---

Thirdly, overall change in displacement is how much it changed location, $\Delta \vec{s}$ as a vector. Distance is how far of a path it traveled to get there. But in the limit, meaning as derivatives, they are the same magnitude $$|\frac{d \vec{s}}{dt}| =\frac{dl}{dt}$$
That says velocity is same magnitude as speed. There are also these things ‘average speed’ and ‘average velocity’:
$$|\frac{\Delta \vec{s}}{\Delta t}| \neq \frac{\Delta l}{\Delta t}$$

---

Finally, $\vec{s}$, a displacement “vector” is actually only a coordinate, $(x, y, z)$. Tells you the location in space. If you want to imagine an arrow from the origin to that coordinate you can, but don’t have to. The change in the coordinate is the change in the displacement vector is the change in location is $\Delta \vec{s}$. If you divide by time, you get average velocity $\vec{v_{avg}}=\frac{\Delta \vec{s}}{\Delta t}$, as a vector, which is not average speed because we may have taken a long path to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a vector quantity since it has both magnitude and direction. Moreover, $dl/dt$ will be equal to the speed at a particular instant while $ds/dt$ is equal to the velocity at a particular instant. The magnitude of instantaneous velocity at a particular instant (T) is equal to $ds/dt$ at $t=T$ when its direction is tangential to the trajectory of the particle.

Comment: if you are discussing vectors you should use the vector using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/550071).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).